# python code is not running.I am calculating prime factors of a number (project euler problem - 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to calculate prime factors of a number in python `python 3.8.2` `32bit` (when i pass 35 in code its output should be 7,and so on).
But for some reason the program does not return any answer (when i click run the cmd does not output anything).But when i run this javascript, the exact same code works there.
 (Previously i had an array(list) to which i would append prime factors and at last i would pop the last element which worked for smaller numbers , but for really large numbers i would get a Memory error,so i converted it to use only one variable which will be updated for every while loop).
  What is going on here ??

My code is :

```
import math
# Computes only prime factors of n
def compute(n):
    arr = 0
    # Checks if n is divisible by 2, and if it is divisible,returns 2 because there will be no any other 
    # prime factor.
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return 2
    # Now that 2 is eliminated we only check for odd numbers upto (square root of n)+1 
    for i in range(1, round(math.sqrt(n)) + 1, 2):
        while n % i == 0:
            arr = n/i
            n /= i

    return str(arr)

print(compute(81))
```

I am a newbie in python so plz tell me if i have made any silly mistakes.
Ty.

Comment: In Python 3, If you want integer division, you need to use `//` and not `/`

Comment: Did you mean: `if n % i == 0:`?

Comment: thank you @Adam.Er8 both. but this is still not working for really large numbers like i want to calculate factor for 600851475143 whose ans is 6857. For this large number i am getting 1 as output.

Comment: and thank you @quamrana as well, because of you my code gave at least some output.

Comment: In the for loop, did you print `i` or `arr` or `n` to see what may be happening?

Comment: Did you try iterating *backwards* (from large to small) and returning the first one you find? - `for i in range(round(math.sqrt(n)) + 1, 1, -2):`?

Comment: iterating backwards would have given weird results i want check only for odd numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I think counting upto 600 billion is ridiculous(considering that i am on a 32 bit system). So here is the final code that i am setteling on which gives answer in acceptable time upto 99 million, without using any array and only 1 for loop.

```
from math import ceil
# Computes only prime factors of n
def compute(n):
    arr = 0
    # Checks if n is divisible by 2, and if it is divisible,sets arr =2 
    if n % 2 == 0:
        arr = 2
    # Now that 2 is eliminated we only check for odd numbers upto (square root of n)+1 
    for i in range(1, ceil(n/2) + 1, 2):
        if n % i == 0:
            arr = i
            n //= i

    return str(arr)

print(compute(999999999))
```

P.S.:- If you see any possible improvement in my code plz tell me.

Answer (score 1):

For numbers that are not divisible by 2, your code runs into an infinite loop at 
`while n%i == 0`

For numbers that are divisible by 2, your function returns 2. The execution of the return statement exits the function.

Even if you change the while in `while n%i == 0` to `if n% == 0` the function will not work.

You will have to restructure your code.

An easy fix would be to check for all factors of a number till n/2 + 1 and return the factors (in a list) that are prime (which can be checked using a separate isprime function.

```
def isprime(n):
    for x in range(2,n//2+1):
        if n%x==0:
            return False
    return True

def compute(n):
    arr = [] 
    for i in range(2, n//2+1):
       if n % i == 0:
            if isprime(i):
                arr.append(i)

    return arr
```

Comment: Yes it works but for small numbers only not for very large numbers. and also i dont want that array eating more memory.btw thank you for your work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all prime factors (which i guess) you shouldn't return values before you have all prime factors in a list for example.

And with this programm you only check once for a 2. But 4 has 2*2. Put it in a loop.

Comment: i dont want how much time the factor comes, i just want the maximum factor.The programme collapses for large numbers only.For smaller number it is giving correct output.See the comments below the question for more recent info.

Comment: I wrote a new comment which should solve your problem. Have a look

Answer (score 0):

So this code saves all prime factors in a list:

```
from math import sqrt, ceil

def get_prime_factors(n):
    prime_factors = []

    while n > 1:
        for i in range (2, ceil(sqrt(n))+1):
            if n % i == 0:
                possible_prime_number = i
                while True:
                    for j in range(2, possible_prime_number//2-1):
                        if possible_prime_number % j == 0:
                            possible_prime_number //= j
                            break
                    prime_factors.append(possible_prime_number)
                    n //= possible_prime_number
                    break

    return prime_factors
```

if you only want the highest one replace `return prime_factors` with `return max(prime_factors)`

Comment: I implemented this but this isnt working either. and also if it did i mean it has a for loop inside a for loop inside a while loop which is utterly time consuming. But thank you for your work.